# Is there a way I can compare a python output with the data present in dynamoDB in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using textract to extract data from an image, say an Id card and want to compare it with the user input that is stored in dynamoDB through a hosted UI or web application.
So how can I pass the extracted text to dynamoDB and make the comparison or vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use Boto3 to pull query the information from the dynamo then compare it with regular python coding.

Boto3 is the AWS SDK for python. If you want to interact with AWS services with python in any manner - and I mean any - Boto3 does it. (And any is not hyperbole. Aws services are developed API first, and the SDKs just are using thaf API.)

Comment: Ya I have been using boto3 for textract as well... Ok will try this approach. Thanks for answering.